# Backbone.js Collection fetch success return

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to get return from Backbone.js Collection fetch using code similar to one below. How do I bypass rest ?

```
var myData = getCollection();

getCollection(){
   this.collection = fetchCollection.fetch({
     success: function(collection, data) {
       collectionData = fetchCollection.toJSON();
       return collectionData; 
     }
  },this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` calls the underlying sync methods, `Backbone.sync`. You can either override the sync method of individual the collections or models, or replace `Backbone.sync` with your own. One such alternative sync implementation for instance is the Backbone localStorage adaptor which stores to localStorage instead of using REST to talk to a server.